# Printing ragged array column by column

Tags: java, arrays

Given an array of integers with rows of different lengths, is it possible to print the whole two-dimensional array but doing so column by column? I understand how to do it row by row but I am struggling with this.

```
int[][] a = new int[5][];

a[0] = new int[4];
a[1] = new int[2];
a[2] = new int[5];
a[3] = new int[3];
a[4] = new int[1];

int longestRowLength = a[0].length;
for(i = 1; i < a.length; i++)
{
    if(a[i].length > longestRowLength)
        longestRowLength = a[i].length;
}

for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < a[i].length; j++)
    {
        a[i][j] = rand.nextInt(10);
        System.out.print(a[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}

for(j = 0; j < longestRowLength; j++)
{
    for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        if(a[i].length < longestRowLength)
            continue;
        System.out.print(a[i][j]);
    }
}
}
```

I have done this but the issue is with how to recognize we are going out of bounds with one of the arrays. My if(a[i].length < longestRowLength doesn't work as it will not even print any numbers if its length is not the longest ones. How can I achieve this?

EDIT:

Ok I have changed that line to:

```
        if(longestRowLength - a[i].length > 0 && (j+1) > a[i].length)
            continue;
        System.out.print(a[i][j]);
```

Now it works but it prints the columns as rows. Is there anyway to make it print column by column but to make it print just like it would with rows? (P.S. yeah the first condition of the if statement is unecessary).

Answer (score 0):

Replace your last loop with:

```
for(j = 0; j < longestRowLength; j++)
{
    for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        if(a[i].length <= j)
            continue;
        System.out.print(a[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Prints the columns one by one.

Instead of:

```
        if(a[i].length <= j)
            continue;
```

you can do:

```
        if(a[i].length <= j) {
            System.out.print(' ');
            continue;
        }
```

to leave a space for arrays which are too short. This way you print the transposed “jagged” matrix.